# Eclipse editor draws horizontal/vertical lines during scrolling down/right

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, eclipse-mars

The following thing happens when I just **scroll down/right** the code in the editor using the **mouse** (both using the wheel and the click-and-scroll, with the **keyboard** the problem doesn't exist).

[image]

It clearly looks like an editor re-paint problem. Instead, when I **scroll up/left**, the orange lines disappear.

I have already tried with no success the solutions proposed at [Eclipse Mars blurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361719/eclipse-mars-blurs) and [Eclipse Mars Scrolling in Lubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154479/eclipse-mars-scrolling-in-lubuntu).

**EDIT**:

No update for Eclipse are available (I have the latest version)

Comment: Same thing here, I updated this morning